# To fetch the record from Table_A only when it's all associated records which is present in Table_B meets the particular criteria

Tags: sql-server

For Ex:
There are two tables:

1. Table 1 - Teacher,
2. Table 2 - Student

In Teacher table, It contains the details of teachers

```
Teacher_Id  &thinsp;    Teacher_Name<br/>
1   &emsp; &emsp;  &emsp; &emsp;    Akshay<br/>
2   &emsp; &emsp; &emsp;  &emsp;    Rohan<br/>
3   &emsp; &emsp;  &emsp; &emsp;    Suresh<br/>
4   &emsp;  &emsp; &emsp;  &emsp;   Naresh<br/>
```

In Student table, It contain the details of students

```
Student_Id &thinsp; Student_Name&thinsp;    Teacher_Id&thinsp;  Marks<br/>
1&emsp; &emsp;  &emsp; &emsp;   Abhi&emsp; &emsp;  &emsp; &emsp;    1&emsp; &emsp;  &emsp; &emsp;   50<br/>
2&emsp; &emsp;  &emsp; &emsp;   Kumar&thinsp; &emsp;  &emsp; &emsp; 2&emsp; &emsp;  &emsp; &emsp;   28<br/>
3&emsp; &emsp;  &emsp; &emsp;   Rahul&thinsp; &emsp;  &emsp; &emsp; 2&emsp; &emsp;  &emsp; &emsp;   90<br/>
4&emsp; &emsp;  &emsp; &emsp;   Mohan&thinsp; &emsp;  &emsp; &emsp; 4&emsp; &emsp;  &emsp; &emsp;   39<br/>
5&emsp; &emsp;  &emsp; &emsp;   Anil&emsp; &emsp;  &emsp; &emsp;    3&emsp; &emsp;  &emsp; &emsp;   51<br/>
6&emsp; &emsp;  &emsp; &emsp;   Jack&emsp; &emsp;  &emsp; &emsp;    4&emsp; &emsp;  &emsp; &emsp;   38<br/>
7&emsp; &emsp;  &emsp; &emsp;   Daniel&ensp; &emsp;  &emsp; &emsp;  2&emsp; &emsp;  &emsp; &emsp;   78<br/>
8&emsp; &emsp;  &emsp; &emsp;   Arun&emsp; &emsp;  &emsp; &emsp;    3&emsp; &emsp;  &emsp; &emsp;   66<br/>
9&emsp; &emsp;  &emsp; &emsp;   Mark&emsp; &emsp;  &emsp; &emsp;    1&emsp; &emsp;  &emsp; &emsp;   43<br/>
10&ensp; &emsp;  &emsp; &emsp;  Mukesh&ensp; &emsp;  &emsp; &emsp;  4&emsp; &emsp;  &emsp; &emsp;   99<br/>
```

As you can see that one teacher is associated with multiple students.
I want to pick those teacher whose all students are passed in exam(Passing marks is 40). 
For Ex: Teacher with Teacher_Id = 2 is associated with 3 student with marks 28,90,78 respectively. Here student with marks 28 fails in exam. So, We will not pick that teacher. We will not select those teacher whose even one student having less than 40 marks. We have to select those teacher whose all students score more than 40 marks.

Answer (score 0):

We can use conditional aggregation here:

```
SELECT
    t.Teacher_Name,
    t.Teacher_Id
FROM Teacher t
INNER JOIN Student s
    ON t.Teacher_Id = s.Teacher_Id
GROUP BY
    t.Teacher_Name,
    t.Teacher_Id
HAVING
    COUNT(CASE WHEN s.Marks < 40 THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

Another option uses `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT
    t.Teacher_Name,
    t.Teacher_Id
FROM Teacher t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Student s
                  WHERE t.Teacher_Id = s.Teacher_Id AND s.Marks < 40);
```